# Select relevant data to feed model

Tags: outliers

I am building a regression algorithm to predict the cost of a product defined by several features.
I use a supervised rule-based model to do the predictions.

The dataset is based on former observations of the product and its final price. My concern is that for some of the observations, the buying price was not optimal and thus not representative.

**I would like to be able to determine which data is representative and should be included in the training set, and which data should be left aside** (with ML techniques).

- My first thought was to train the model with every data in the dataset, then test the model on every data and exclude the ones exceeding the prediction above a certain percentage. I am very sceptical about the good results of this method.
- Then I thought about clustering. After centering and scaling my data, I applied a distance matrix, k-mean algorithm and dendogram (including the output -the price-) but it is not easy to interpret which data is too expensive as the price varies a lot depending on the product features.

My questions are the following :

1. Do my methods make sense and are they likely to help me ?
2. Is there any technique allowing to select only the consistent data ? I searched but failed in finding some readings about this topic.

Any help or thought would be very welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which observations are incorrect, then you should remove them unless you want capture that effect in your model.

Your problem sounds like an outlier detection problem. Depending on your assumptions, you can use a variety of methods out there. One simple example: If you plan on using linear regression, there is a lot of well cited literature on outlier detection in a linear model.
Methods such as Studentized-residuals, Leverage using the hat matrix or simply looking at the residual plot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was looking for outlier detection problem.
Here is a useful link I used to understand it better :
https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/339/